# How to properly setup poetry environment with python?

Tags: python, python-poetry

This is my first time setting up poetry. My project structure looks like this:

```
bert-api
    bert_api
        bert
            __init__.py
            predict.py
        data
            docs
    tests
    venv
    poetry.lock
    pyproject.toml
```

I created my poetry using following command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python

#change python version
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.6'
python --version

#start a new project
poetry new bert-api

#open the project
poetry install
poetry shell

poetry env use /usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

now to run *predict.py* i go:

```
 (venv) (base) a10.12@MacBook-Air bert-api % poetry install
 (venv) (base) a10.12@MacBook-Air bert-api % poetry run script
```

and it works perfectly:

However as far as I know I suppose to use

```
poetry install
poetry shell

Spawning shell within /Users/a10.12/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/bert-api-w7KuvcmX-py3.6
a10.12@MacBook-Air bert-api % . /Users/a10.12/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/bert-api-w7KuvcmX-py3.6/bin/activate
```

and then run

```
poetry run script
```

but if I do this way I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'VersionConstraint'
```

What am I doing wrong?

My pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "bert-api"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [name]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6.7"
deeppavlov = "^0.15.0"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
script = "bert_api.bert.predict:main"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api
```

"

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to specify the python version before i do poetry install and poetry shell

```
poetry env use python3.6
```